# WooCommerce back button on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I have made a "back" button on my product pages with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'back_button', 10 );

function back_button() {
  global $product;
  echo ' <button class="product-back-button" type="button" onclick="history.back();"> << Vissza</button> '; 
}
```

The only problem with it: when I make some action on the product page like "add to cart" and then hit the back button it just reloads the page and I need to push it again for the expected behavior.

Do you know any fix for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Sound like that the add to cart button manipulates the browser history. So when you add something, it goes one forward. If you press the back button now, you need to press it twice to go back. The only way to fix is is in my eyes to define a link or to call a custom JS function which checks how much times you have to go back. All in all a bit unlikely. So I would prefer the static link button.

Comment: You'd need to do a fair bit of Javascript coding to get this going. What you could do is store the [history.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length) property using a [cookie](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) when you first enter the page, then your button could call the [History.Go()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) method with the current history.length subtracted from the old history.length. With some special code to deal with the case where history.length has gone back to 0 after reaching 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'back_button', 10 );
function back_button() {
global $product;
echo ' <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go Back</a> '; 
}
```

to place a back 1 link next to cart button. I hope this helps a bit.